# Can i generate unique text 1 lacs time in javascript through any method who does not need any framework?

Tags: javascript, puzzle

i have a word from A to Z. all word should in small latter (Capital not include) and  1 to 9 (included all special word who can be used in email address (just for a test)).

how i can generate unique 1 lacs text who never repeat itself. can anyone solve this puzzle.

i want a another thing that all words should not more then 10 char and not should minimum 6 char long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the characters in an array. Copy the array as the source of a new line. Randomly *slice* words from the array and put them in the line (use `Math.random() * array.length | 0`). Keep going for the required number of words.

You can also just use a string and `charAt(index)` if you only want single characters, but you have to keep cutting out the character that you select which is likely less efficient than using *array.slice*.

Whatever suits though, since performance is likely irrelevant.